# If I set up the Firebase, the install of nativescript app will be successful, but won't run

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I don't have much knowledge about Android.
I am using nativescript-vue and nativescript is 8.x version.
When I first create the ns-vue template and run the "ns run android" or "ns debug android" command, the app is installed on the connected device and runs automatically.
However, if I enter "ns run android" after setting up the Firebase, the install will be successful but the app will not run.
Running "ns debug android --debug-brk" results are the same and no errors appear on the console.
I just created the Firebase project and followed the stated flow.

**Firebase setup flow I did:**

1. I changed the package value in the file "App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml".
   firebase: "com.xx.xx"
   before AndroidManifest.xml: `"\\PACKAGE\\"`
   after AndroidManifest.xml: "com.xx.xx"
2. I downloaded "Google-services.json" and copied it to the "platforms/android/app" folder.
3. I added applic plugin: 'com.Google.gms.Google-services' to the first line of "App_Resources/Android/app.gradle" and injected two dependencies.
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
4. I added classpath 'com.Google.gms:Google-services:4.3.8' from "platforms/android/build.gradle".
5. When I run the "ns run android" or "ns run debug" command, no errors appear and the "Successfully installed on device" log is displayed, but the app does not run.

No event occurs even if I launch the app.
I made the @loaded event call alert function and wrapped it with a try-catch phrase, but I can't see any error log or alert.

**What I've tried:**

1. ns run android --clean
2. ns run debug --debug-brk
3. ns build --release --aab --copy-to=[path] → aab to apks → install pak → no alert
4. ns clean
5. Try connecting to the actual device, turning off wifi.
6. Turn it to the emulator. (API 30)
7. I created a new project and tried the same thing, but the results didn't change.
8. Afterwards, I return the app.gradle, build.gradle to its original state and delete the Google-services.json file, but the app does not run automatically.

What did I miss?

ps. I know that there is a nativescript-firebase plug-in.
+I created a template with ns create my-blank-vue --template @nativescript/template-blank-vue.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found problem.

**Problem:**
I changed the package value in the file "App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml".
firebase: "com.xx.xx"
before AndroidManifest.xml: `"__PACKAGE__"`
after AndroidManifest.xml: "com.xx.xx"

but Nativescript doc:
The NativeScript CLI build system will set them as the package attribute in the generated project in `platforms/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. In the app/App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml it will use a placeholder: `package="__PACKAGE__"`. ***Do not modify the package attribute there.***

**Solved:**

1. I reverted the file `App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` like this:  `package="__PACKAGE__"`
2. update package value from `platforms/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:
   `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.app" ...>`
3. add `applicationId` properties same with package name to `App_Resources/Android/src/main/app.gradle`:

   android {
   defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.company.app"
   minSdkVersion 17
   generatedDensities = []
   }
4. update id from `nativescript.config.ts` file:
   `id: 'com.company.app' // match application id`
5. cmd: `ns platform remove android; ns prepare android`

**Refernce:**
https://docs.nativescript.org/releasing#overview
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id?hl=ko